# Jhipster Inter Server Communication

Tags: java, rest, service, jhipster, communication

First of all I know i need to write service that does not depend on each other but i have to cause of some requirements from the client.

So now the problem is I have no idea how to request the data from one service to another service, I have 2 services lets call service1 and middlewareService, so the middleware service gets the details from some third party api, and the middleware is not linked to the database. so now I need to call a function in the middleware and get the details from service1 so that I can put save in the database and send it back to our application users.

I understand that this can be done through feginClients but I have no Idea on how to do it? can anybody help?

Thank you for your assistance, ;)

Answer (score 0):

IT is fine i figured out how to achieve this using fegin client, thank you stackoverflow.

Comment: This is not really an answer that could help someone finding your question. You should either add details to your answer or delete your question.